# My questions do not appear on Stack Overflow main page

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, questions

Few months back, when I asked some question at stackoverflow.com, it used to appear on its main page questions list, in just few minutes. But for my last 2 questions, (during last 20 days) I've noticed that my question do not appear on main page. I even see other questions time stamps as 1s ago, 3s ago, 1hour ago, etc. Then, how come my question do not appear? Is there something changed? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's probably because of cache in your browser, do hard refresh then you can see it in action - ctrl+f5

Comment: @Bala Thank you. I'll try this in my very next question, if i face the same issue :)

Comment: Maybe you gave it a tag that you have in your ignored tags list.

Comment: The default tab of the main page is *interesting*: Maybe your question is just not that interesting to appear there.

Comment: Caching. It's always caching.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Not in this case! There's a tuning mechanism for front page.